# Fact And Dimension from the One Table

Tags: sql-server-2005

Hi i m new to SSAS 2005/08. I want to create Cube from 1 table , Stored in OLTP Database. Table containg billions of records.

how to select dimension and Fact from this alone table.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

A dimension derived from data in the fact table is known as a degenerate dimension:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_dimension

Here's a link discussing how to model an data as both a dimension and fact attribute, if that's what you're wanting to do:

http://www.ralphkimball.com/html/07dt/KU97ModelingDataBothFactDimen.pdf